# Android WorkManager - Is possible to start it in and Activity and check the status in another?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Is possible to start a workManager task in ex. FirstActivity and read the status(if finish or not) in secondActivity? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a work using work manager and assign that work a tag.

```
val manager = WorkManager.getInstance()
OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(YourWorker::class.java)
                    .addTag("YourTag")
                    .build()
```

And to get the status you use the following:

```
val info = manager.getWorkInfosByTag("YourTag")
```